# Get SequenceNumber by UniqueID in Aspose.Mail Pop3

Tags: email, pop3, aspose

I use Aspose.Mail in my project and I have a collection of UniqueIDs and I want to retrieve Pop3MessageInfo. All method that do this work by SequenceNumber. Is there any method to get SequenceNumber by UniqueID?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature available at the moment and provision of the same depends whether the POP3 protocol supports this or not. Please follow the discussion on your [forum thread](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/756706/get-sequencenumber-by-uniqueid.aspx) on Aspose.Email forum to get updated about it.